# CORS Policy Error When Integrating Mailchimp with Gatsby and Strap

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, strapi, mailchimp

I am encountering a CORS policy error when trying to integrate Mailchimp with my Gatsby project. The error message states: "has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Expected Behavior:

The subscription request should be successfully sent to Mailchimp, and the user should be subscribed to the newsletter.

here is my code:

```js
const SignUpBanner: React.FC<SignUpBannerProps> = ({}: SignUpBannerProps) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [subscriptionStatus, setSubscriptionStatus] = useState('');

  const handleSubscribe = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        'https://xxx.us21.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=xxxx&id=xxxx&f_id=xxxx',
        {
          EMAIL: email,
          SIGNUP: 'HOME', // Specify your signup location here
        },
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          },
        }
      );

      if (response.status === 200) {
        setSubscriptionStatus('success');
      } else {
        setSubscriptionStatus('error');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setSubscriptionStatus('error');
      console.error('Error subscribing:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={`${paddingForBanner}`}>
      <div
        className={`${paddingForSignUpContent} d-xl-flex d-lg-flex justify-content-xl-between justify-content-lg-between`}
      >
        <div className={`${signUpHeading}`}>
          Stay connected through our newsletter!
        </div>
        <div className={`${signUptitle}`}>
          Subscribe to our newsletter and get the latest insights on history, art &
          art & culture in your inbox.
          <div className={`${emailInput} d-xl-flex d-lg-flex`}>
            <div className={`${inputDiv}`}>
              <input
                type="email"
                placeholder="Enter Email"
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                className={`${customInputField} ${emailfield} form-control`}
              />
            </div>
            <div
              className={`${signUpButton} d-flex d-lg-flex flex-row flex-lg-row justify-content-end align-items-center justify-content-lg-center `}
              onClick={handleSubscribe}
            >
              <div className={`${signUpText}`}>
                {subscriptionStatus === 'success' ? 'Subscribed!' : 'SIGNUP'}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SignUpBanner;
```

How can I resolve this CORS issue ?

Comment: Are you _supposed_ to consume this API from the client side ...?

Comment: Yes, I consume APIs from the client side

Comment: Yes, I can see that you are _trying_ to do that; but my question is, are you _supposed to_? If they don't enable CORS from their end (based on some configuration, connection of some client ID with a specific domain or something), then you will only be able to access this API from the server side, resp. using a "CORS proxy."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I send a MailChimp API request via JavaScript in Google Tag Manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56241585/how-can-i-send-a-mailchimp-api-request-via-javascript-in-google-tag-manager).  This also has important reading why what you are trying to do is a shockingly bad idea

Answer (score 1):

## why is this happening?

Mailchimp does not allow you to integrate with any resources or information of the website's origin.

CORS stands for cross-origin-resource-sharing, it's a mechanism that all browsers use for security reasons. in order to set this policy to your website you must add a HTTP header named `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` like below:

```http
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://foo.example
```

in your case `https://xxx.us21.list-manage.com` CORS header is set to:
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://list-manage.com`
which means only the HTTP requests with the origin set to `https://list-manage.com` are allowed to send request to `https://xxx.us21.list-manage.com`

## how can you solve this?

There is no way that you can change the Origin HTTP header, there's only two option for this:

1. requesting from the origin https://list-manage.com

you have to send a request from the same server that includes the origin `https://list-manage.com`. subdomains might be included too, it depends on what the Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set to.
which means you can send a request from https://subdomain.list-manage.com

2. change the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to `*`

the developers of Mailchimp should change the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to `*` so anyone can access it and use the resource and the content of the site.

## summery

the developers of Mailchimp made this policy so no one can integrate with their website. only they can change this mechanism