# MailChimp ajax post returns "Recipient has too many recent sign up requests"

Tags: ajax, post, mailchimp

I am trying to make an ajax call that adds a new subscriber to my MailChimp list.
I tried the solution on this thread
[Mailchimp subscribe using jQuery AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526408/mailchimp-subscribe-using-jquery-ajax)

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'http://xxxxx.us#.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json??u=xxxxx&id=xxxx&c=?',
    type: 'GET',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
       if (data['result'] != "success") {
            //ERROR
            console.log(data['msg']);
       } else {
           console.log('Hooray');
       }
    }
});
```

However I am getting an error that says

> Recipient has too many recent sign up request

I noticed that whenever I add post to the sign-up URL the error appears 
Even when opening the sign-up form URL from the browser

Comment: Same issue here, did you find any solution?

Comment: I'm getting the error message, have you found any solutions yet?

Answer (score 10):

Make sure the email field being sent is all caps, so your data object might look like:

```
var data = { email: "foo@bar.com" }
```

When, it should be:

```
var data = { EMAIL: "foo@bar.com" }
```

Answer (score 2):

just have had the same issue when i was using the link that my co-worker created on Mailchimp.

Problem solved for me when I copy the link (shorter URL) under signup form>Create forms>copy URL in Mailchimp.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think i can use the short url in the ajax call, it has to contain post-json

Answer (score 2):

Had the same error and changing the email name property to uppercase "EMAIL" in the form has resolved the issue.

```
<input type="email" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Email address" required="" name="MERGE0" id="MERGE0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you disabling the form elements while it's sending? If you are, you'll need to set you `data` variable before disabling the form elements.

Otherwise `.serialize()` will return empty.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had JSON.stringify(data). Once I removed JSON.Stringify() and just passed in the data object, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem. You have to change 'name' attributes for all inputs in your form to the same as in mailchimp 'name' attributes.